# jQuery height returns wrong value

Tags: jquery, css, height, each

I want to get the height value of a heading and a paragraph. So that when I change their size, I can set the offset to make them fit underneath eachother, because their are set to absolute.

I'd usually do it differently but I have to do it with absolute positions, because it's the way this responsive slider works.

However when I use each() it only correctly works on the first slide (the current one) but not on all the others. Even though the slides aren't changed in size, when they are moved off to the side.

```
<div class="slide-content">
    <h2><span class="slide-title"><?php the_title() ?></span></h2>
    <p class="slide-text"><?php echo $text; ?></p>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $meta["page"] ) ?>" class="da-link">> Jetzt Informieren</a>
</div>

function test() {
    $(".slide-content").each(function() {
        var content = $(this);

        var title = content.find(".slide-title");
        var text = content.find(".slide-text");
        var link = content.find(".da-link");

        var titleheight = title.height();
        var textheight = text.height();

        text.css("top",titleheight+"px");
        link.css("top",titleheight+textheight+"px");

    });
}
```

this is my function.

The values I get are:

```
title: 122 text: 54 
title: 164 text: 144 
title: 164 text: 126
```

The first pair is correct. The others are wrong. So it only works on the current slide.
This would be different depending on the current slide shown. The slides aren't set to display:none when they move off, all that changes is the left offset.

The function is called like this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        test();
    });
```

When I check with Google Chrome the element sizes stays the same when the slide moves of the stage.

I've been having trouble with each() a lot. So what could this be?

Comment: Are the subsequent slides added by a JS plugin, too? That's because if those elements are dynamically generated, you'll have to use `.on()`, `.live()` or `.delegate()` beforehand (although I strongly recommend the first option). p/s: A fiddle would help us to visualize your problem. Very. Much.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you first have applied a CSS Reset.

Then in your CSS, try giving line-height in 'em' for the heading and paragraph.